# Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.0.2 pulling .NET framework standard edition in a old MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have a MVC 5 application which uses the full .NET framework ( v 4.6.2)

When i updated my packages on this project , the Json.Net package has been upgraded to 10.0.0.2 
If i run the application after the updated i get the error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, .... The system cannot find the file specified.

The only way to fix this error is to either :

1. Remove the following dependency line from my web.config

   ```
    <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
   ```

or

2. Add the System.Runtime dll as a Nuget package.

I find it very odd that I have to add all the core dll's of the full .NET framework as Nuget packages.

My question is :

Is there something wrong with the Json.Net package and its dependencies ? 
As a nuget package should be able to pull its dependencies automatically but I have to manually install the System.Runtime nuget package for my application to work

or

Has Nuget messed up the dependencies  ?

or

Maybe this is what microsoft expect you to do going forward ?  i.e use nuget packages for even the basic dll's like System.Runtime  **even for** projects which are not based on .NET core or .NET standard libraries.

Edit : Added clarity to question based on comments

Comment: You don't have the full .NET framework, only certain versions of the assemblies. Framework assemblies are released independently  since 4.5 at least. Json.NET does *NOT* download .NET Standard, it downloads the assemblies it needs. That's not what Microsoft expects you to do going forward, the change occured 5 years ago.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos could you explain this a bit more ?

Comment: There's not much to explain. .NET assemblies are developed and distributed through NuGet for 5 years now. Framework versions are only the baselines. You *don't* have to include all of them, only the ones you need. This has nothing to do with .NET Standard. Json.NET simply downloads the assemblies it needs.

Comment: Check [.NET Framework and Out-Of-Band Releases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn151288(v=vs.110).aspx) for more

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so how do u explain the System.Runtime error when updating the Json.NEt package ?  From what i understand if a nuget package has dependency on another Nuget package it pulls that dependency automatically , this is not happening in my case , i am having to manually add the System.Runtime nuget package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this,
I am posting it here as it might end up being useful to someone else.

TL;DR  Nuget messed up.

Long answer ,

I have a Solution with around 100 CSProj files , one of them (Project X) had mistakenly installed the .NET standard library.

A couple of weeks later , a new version of Json.Net got released and I went to the consolidate tab on nuget manager to update and Consolidate the version of Json.Net across the 100 projects in my solution.

This is where the mess up occurred , for some reason Nuget decided to take the Json.Net package which it installed in project X ( with the .NET standard assembly dependency )  and apply it across all my projects including the main Web project.

This meant the web project now wanted version of basic DLL which did not exist in the full .NET framework . E.g , it expected v4.1.1.0 for System.Runtime which is the version .NETStandard 1.3 library expects 
[as shown in the dependency map here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/10.0.2)

This resulted in the error in question above.

The solution in my case was to remove the incorrect package that got added in Project X , uninstall Json.Net package and re install it in all the other projects. This time it got the correct dependency map.